# Add objects and views in table view like the PullDownToRefresh

Tags: ios, tableview, pull

I want to add a label and other objects in table view, but I want to add these objects in the same position in which there is the `PullDownToRefresh` in Twitter app.

How can I do this?

I know that I have to work with content offset of table view, but I really don't know how to add in that position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a template classes from here : http://goo.gl/FGOjb